React-native-splash-screen Resource and asset merger: Can't determine type for tag <ImageView
i was adding react native splash screen on my project , while adding the logo on splash screen, it says
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
ERROR: D:\project\project\android\app\src\main\res\launch_screen\launch_screen.xml: Resource and asset merger: Can't determine type for tag '<ImageView android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:scaleType="center" android:src="@drawable/launch_screen"/>'

the current xml file is this below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/launch_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="center"
  />

</LinearLayout>

i tried bitmap xml and other layout options , without adding the  tag it works but the logo streched out ,
